# Embedding \sigma (or \mu) into R-Markdown quiz question

Tags: r-markdown

I am trying to render the Greek sigma notation within a Quiz in R Markdown. If I use dollar signs, it only italicizes the word \sigma.  If I use
`<span class="math inline">\sigma</span>` I get an error".

```
question_radio(
  "Is this a statement about the standard deviation, $/sigma$, a proportion $p$, or something else?",
  answer("Standard deviation", correct = TRUE),
  answer("Proportion"),
  answer("Something else altogether"),
  allow_retry = TRUE,
  random_answer_order = TRUE
)
```

yields

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC8aJ.png)

```
question_radio(
  "Is this a statement about the standard deviation, <span class="math inline">\mu</span>, a proportion $p$, or something else?",
  answer("Standard deviation", correct = TRUE),
  answer("Proportion"),
  answer("Something else altogether"),
  allow_retry = TRUE,
  random_answer_order = TRUE
)
```

yields

Error in `parse()`:
! :2:67: unexpected symbol
1: question_radio(
2:   "Is this a statement about the standard deviation, <span class="math
^
Backtrace:

1. rmarkdown::run(...)
2. rmarkdown:::shiny_prerendered_app(target_file, render_args = render_args)
3. rmarkdown:::shiny_prerendered_html(input_rmd, render_args)
4. rmarkdown (local) `<fn>`(...)
5. knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
   ...
6. knitr:::eng_r(options)
7. rmarkdown (local) evaluate(...)
8. evaluate::evaluate(code, envir, ...)
9. evaluate:::parse_all.character(...)
10. base::parse(text = x, srcfile = src)
    Execution halted

I have looked through much documentation on writing quizzes, but I've had no luck.

EDIT: Answer: Use `$\sigma$` or `$\\sigma$` within the question function. I mistakenly used forward slashes. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose it in double backslashes to escape the backslash character in R Markdown.
By using `$\\sigma$`, the Greek sigma symbol should be rendered correctly in the quiz question:

```
question_radio(
  "Is this a statement about the standard deviation, $\\sigma$, a proportion $p$, or something else?",
  answer("Standard deviation", correct = TRUE),
  answer("Proportion"),
  answer("Something else altogether"),
  allow_retry = TRUE,
  random_answer_order = TRUE
)
```